# Backtesting :: Migration to Simulated / Real-Time Trading

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading

I am relatively new to backtesting and I want to migrate my system to simulated trading via Amibrokers Interactive Broker's API.

What I have been doing is setting trade delays such that when a **Buy** or **Short** signal occurs, the algorithm buy or short on the next **Open**.

Here is a sample code:

```
**BuySignal = Cross( Close, MA(Close, 100 ) ); 

// buy on the next bar

Buy = Ref( BuySignal, -1);

BuyLimitPrice = Ref( Close, -1) * 0.99;

// now we check if limit was hit

Buy = Buy AND L < BuyLimitPrice;

// if Open price is below the limit, then we use Open for entry

BuyPrice = Min( Open, BuyLimitPrice );**
```

The question is that: When you migrate this to real-time or simulated trading, what price do you use for **Open**?

This is what I am struggling with - there are two options:

a) Use real-time data for the price of the stock (i.e., GetRTData( "Last" ) ) which is the "last" value that the ticker was traded at, or

b) Use the value of **Open** of the stock for that bar, which can be obtained by the system.

Which value is the correct or the best one to use (i.e, `a` or `b`)?